# nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.site.com" on 0.0.0.0:443/0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: nginx

While running a dry-run on certbot autorenewal, I'm getting the following warnings:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert not due for renewal, but simulating renewal for dry run
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for example.com
http-01 challenge for www.example.com
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
new certificate deployed with reload of nginx server; fullchain is
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem (success)
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates above have not been saved.)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

The rules of the Nginx configuration should 1) redirect all http to https, 2) redirect all non-www to www. It does it, which is good, but there's this warning which shows it could be improved.

It's probably very obvious what is wrong with my current config, but I couldn't find how to keep everything working correctly while fixing it. Here is my config file (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com`):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.example.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/example/code/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/wrappers/ruby;

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;

        add_header ETag "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:**

The third server block should be just:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate ... etc etc 
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

**Explanation**

You have two server names and two ports, therefore 4 combinations

- example.com:80
- [www.example.com:80](http://www.example.com:80)
- example.com:443
- [www.example.com:443](http://www.example.com:443)

Each one of those should be handled once and only once on your servers blocks. However

> nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

- it's declared once in the first block, twice in the third block

> nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

- once in the first block, twice in the third block

> nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored

- once in the second block, twice in the third block

> nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored

- twice in the third block

the general logic of your redirection flow should be:

```
# handle example.com:80
# handle www.example.com:80
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# handle  example.com:443
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate ... etc etc 

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# handle www.example.com:443
 server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate ... etc etc 

    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example/code/public;
 }
```

Please note you still need a certificate for non www host even if will be inmediately redirected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations, I’ll try that and keep you updated!

Comment: I tried but the warning stays there... I restarted nginx and passenger (in case) but it's still the same. I will update my original post to reflect my current Nginx configuration.

Comment: Any idea why it would continue to show these warnings?

Comment: have you updated the warning messages as well, in your question? are you sure no other enabled sites do mention www.example.com or example.com? Please, make sure to paste your current vhost file. Remember certbot alters it when yo tell it to redirect http to https

Comment: Actually, the warning is repeated many times (25-30 times, before and after the challenges - I'll update with the current output). The config file in my post is the current one (modified with your advices).

Comment: Great and useful answer! thanks a lot @ffflabs